# WNS failing all Amazon SNS notifications

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, amazon-sns, wns

I'm trying to send toast notifications to my Windows Phone 8.1 apps from the Amazon SNS console but the WNS server is refusing all of my messages. The issue probably lies in the way I format my messages as **I am able to send and receive raw notifications**.

Some of the message formats I've tried:

Default from amazon console:

```
{
  "default": "test", 
  "WNS" : "<badge version\"1\" value\"23\"/>"
}
```

From Microsoft MSDN:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template=\"ToastText01\">
            <text id=\"1\">bodyText</text>
        </binding>  
    </visual>
</toast>
```

XAML format:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">
    <wp:Toast>
        <wp:Text1>[string]</wp:Text1>
        <wp:Text2>[string]</wp:Text2>
        <wp:Param>[string]</wp:Param>
    </wp:Toast>
</wp:Notification>
```

In my logs I can see that all of my `FAILURE` response.
Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956932/amazon-sns-console-to-push-raw-notification-to-wns and my comments there.
have you been able to fix this?

Comment: @bc3tech No I wasn't, I switched to MPNS. Which had limited functionality but at least it worked!

Comment: gotchya. unfortunately i don't believe this is an option for UWP apps :/