# Amazon SNS console to push raw notification to WNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, wns

I am testing out using AWS SNS to send push notifications to my windows app via SNS.  I have done the work configuring the application and my endpoint.  However, I am unable to figure out how to send a raw notification to my app.  The JSON to create a badge update seems to work:

```
{
   "WNS" : "<badge version\"1\" value\"23\"/>"
}
```

However, whenever I use the Raw message format, it seems to wrap the message I created and instead sends a toast message with the contents I entered.  Is there any way in the console to send a pure Raw notification?

I.E. in the Raw message area I enter: 'test123', it sends a Toast notification with the following xml.

```
<toast><visual version="1"><binding template="ToastText01"><text id="1">test123</text></binding></visual></toast>
```

Comment: I've found the same. Furthermore, if you were to use the JSON generator, you'll see it creates - by default - a `badge` notification. if you swap that out for the `toast` template, you'll still receive a `badge` notification in the app, with the entire XML contents of the toast template. I've opened a support request through our enterprise agreement but I welcome any ideas somebody else might have.

Comment: I ended up just writing a java application to test it out...

Comment: gotchya. unfortunately not a viable solution for me; i don't have access to the AWS secret/id to write a 3rd party app. that's managed by the guys that write our APIs and they prefer to write an API to do the AWS work so we don't have to have the secret/id floating around in disparate apps.